# Strings são identicas, mas quando comparo retorna false

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     String comando2 = "fim";
     String comando = input.nextLine();
     
     
     System.out.print(comando==comando2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quando você utiliza o operador `==` para comparar uma String, você está comparando o endereço de memória dela e não o conteúdo, mesmo o valores sendo iguais cada String foi alocada em uma posição diferente da memória.

Se você quiser comparar String você deve utilizar o método `equals()`
que irá verificar o conteúdo das 2 strings

```java
String comando2 = "fim";
String comando = new String("fim");


System.out.print(comando==comando2); //False
System.out.print(comando.equals(comando2)); //True
}
```

Comment: Nossa, era isso mesmo. valeu demais!

Comment: Você chegou a testar a sua afirmação? Não! em ambos os casos retorna true, veja https://ideone.com/EztuYx

Comment: opa Augusto vc está certo, quando eu comparo 2 strings literais o compilador já faz este ajuste, erro meu. No entanto se fizer `New String("fim") == comando` irá retornar falso :) no caso do exemplo do joao  é gerado um novo objeto String quando ele faz a leitura via terminal por conta disso o resultado será falso.

Comment: @JhonathanWolff, edite a resposta e corrija a informação.